# Replace old eregi function PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

I'm having problems to fix this old PHP eregi funxtion becouse it uses IN parameter..
It's script for captcha generation class_log.php from Matthieu MARY

old code:

```
$sMotif = "--$sIN ([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4},)*([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}){1}";
if ((eregi("$sMotif ",$this->sParam))||(eregi("$sMotif$",$this->sParam))){
    $this->aParam['bExtension'] = TRUE;
    $this->aParam['aExtension'] = $this->_PARAM_get_extension($sIN);
    $this->aParam['inExtension'] = ($sIN=='e');
    $this->aParam['iParameters']++;
}
```

I try with this, but not sure is it correct?

```
$sMotif = "/--$sIN ([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4},)*([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}){1}/i";
if ((preg_match("$sMotif ",$this->sParam))||(eregi("$sMotif$",$this->sParam))){
    $this->aParam['bExtension'] = TRUE;
    $this->aParam['aExtension'] = $this->_PARAM_get_extension($sIN);
    $this->aParam['inExtension'] = ($sIN=='e');
    $this->aParam['iParameters']++;
}
```

tnx

Comment: `preg_match("/$pattern/");`

Comment: No, it isn't because you add a character (a space) outside of the delimiters `/`. A better approach consists to rewrite the pattern to test the two conditions in one shot. A basic tutorial will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I'd do the job:

```
$sMotif = "/--$sIN ([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4},)*([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}) ?/";
if ( preg_match($sMotif,$this->sParam)) {
```